# How can I get a label to show up as a solid piece of text in a cesium entity with a billboard?

Tags: cesiumjs

I have a [sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

When one zooms in, what shows up looks like:

[image: bad image]

The '5' labels do not look right. My only guess for what is happening is the the billboard and the label are trying to occupy the same space and that is not working well.

How can I get a label to show up on top of a billboard and look like a solid character?